# How to search a store in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs

What could I be doing wrong; I only get -1 when I do a search of a store?

> My model

```
Ext.define('app.model.Sections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'title',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'content',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    }
});
```

---

> My Store

```
Ext.define('app.store.Sections', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'app.model.Sections'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,

        model: 'app.model.Sections',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'resources/data/data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

> The `json` file is like this

```
{
    "items": [{
        "id": "27",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "content": "",
        "items": [{
            "id": "85",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "content": "content 2",
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "id": "78",
            "title": "Title 3",
            "content": "content 3",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "29",
        "title": "Title 4",
        "content": "",
        "items": [{
            "id": "97",
            "title": "Title 5",
            "content": "content 5",
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "id": "93",
            "title": "Title 6",
            "content": "content 6",
            "leaf": true
        }, {
            "id": "105",
            "title": "Title 7",
            "content": "content 7",
            "leaf": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

---

I am able to get the store and view the data in the store but the index always comes out -1

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Sections');
 var index = store.findExact('id', 85);
 console.log(store);
 console.log(index);
```

Comment: your ids are strings in the JSON, have you tried `store.findExact('id', '85')`?

Comment: I'm still getting -1 when I pass a string.

Comment: what happens if you do store.findExact('id', 29) or store.findExact('id', '29')?

Comment: what about indexOfId ? do you still get -1 ? Are you sure the store is loaded by the time you try to find the record? Try setting a breakpoint right before the findExact method and see what items the store has in it.

Comment: indexOfId returns -1 also. The store seems to be loaded before the call to indexOfId.

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle so we can try and find the solution?

Comment: Ok, I'll set it up in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanP Are you sure that the store is loaded when you perform the search? try doing it with the store.on('load', function () {...}); event.

Comment: Yes, that helps. I am able to get the index for non leaf records in the tree. I still get -1 when I search for a leaf.

Comment: getNodeById will get the leaf record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used carcel's suggestion to do the `store.on('load', function ());`.

I also changed the data type of `id` to string so there would be no confusion.

```
initialize: function() {

    var sectionID = '85';
    var store = Ext.getStore('Sections');

    // search once the store is loaded
    store.on('load', function() {

            // get the node record
            var record = store.getNodeById(sectionID);

            if (record == null)
                console.log('no record found');
            else {
                var parentPanel = Ext.getCmp('myabouttest');
                parentPanel.setHtml(record.data.content);
                var titlebar = Ext.getCmp('mytitilebar');
                titlebar.setTitle(record.data.title);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The initialize function completes before the store can be loaded so to display the data I have to specify IDs for the panel and the title and then get their components to set the items.

Comment: That really depends on the rest of your code, but at first glance you could declare the record variable before the "on load" method instead of declaring it in the else statement.

Comment: And also, please check http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-isLeaf, I believe you can use getNodeById for all cases and just check if its a leaf with the isLeaf method rather than have three store searches.

Comment: Declaring the variable outside the function and assigning the record to it does not seem to work. I've tried two different ways.